# How do I show a modal dialog that tracks a task?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

It's clear to me if I have a button that triggers an event, but in the case below, I want to pop up a dialog.  The code below is a mess, I don't know how to do this right. I think async/await is part of this, but I'm not clear on this case.

```
class TaskObject : Form
{
    public void MyFunc()
    { 
      MyDialog d = new MyDialog(this);
      d.ShowDialog(); // I don't want any other interaction except this dialog's controls
    }
    internal async Task<bool> LongFunction()
    {
      // ...
      return true;
    }

}
class MyDialog : Form
{
  Task<bool> task;
  public async MyDialog(TaskObject o)
  {
     task = new Task<bool>(o.LongFunction);
     await task;
  }
  void when_LongFunction_does_something_interesting()
  {
    this.MyTextBox.Text = "Something interesting";
  }
  void when_task_completes()
  {
     this.CancelButton.Visible = false;
     this.CloseButton.Visible = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's called [`ShowDialog()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog), not `ShowModal()`.

Comment: What?  My question is 100% different Ahmed.  This is about how to have the dialog operate in parallel with a running task.

Comment: _"This is about how to have the dialog operate in parallel with a running task."_ Where is that task running? In the "parent" form?

Comment: See the constructor?  It's creating a task and running it.  But this code doesn't compile.  I want the dialog to run while the background task is going, and then the task calls upon the dialog to do stuff.

Comment: Assuming `TaskObject` is derived from `Form` and `LongFunction` is a public/internal method in the `o` instance of that form, you can simply make that method async and then call it (and `await` it) in the modal form. Have you tried that? Please include the `LongFunction` method into your question (or at least the signature of that method).

Comment: Is my constructor above not doing exactly what you're asking about?  I'm confused.

Comment: Added definition for LongFunction as requested.

Comment: Please let me know if there's anything not clear in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two points here:

1. The constructor of your form cannot have the `async` modifier. As an alternative, you can use the [`Load` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load) instead.
2. (Optional) You don't need to pass an instance of the "parent" form to the constructor, you can get it directly from the `Owner` property if you use `ShowDialog(this)` instead of `ShowDialog()`.

Also, remember to dispose of any dialog form after you're done with it. Preferably, wrap the usage of it within a [`using` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Here's how I would do it; In the `TaskObject` form:

```
internal async Task<bool> LongFunction()
{
    // Do some magic.
    // await ...

    return true;
}

public void MyFunc()
{
    using (MyDialog d = new MyDialog())
    {
        d.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
```

In the `MyDialog` form:

```
private async void MyDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TaskObject owner = this.Owner as TaskObject;
    await owner.LongFunction();
    when_task_completes();
}
```

---

If you also want to track the progress of `LongFunction`, you can add a [`Progress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) parameter to it and use it like this:

```
internal async Task<bool> LongFunction(IProgress<string> progress)
{
    // Do some magic.
    progress.Report("Something interesting");
    // await ...
    // More magic.
    return true;
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
private async void MyDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TaskObject owner = this.Owner as TaskObject;

    var progress = new Progress<string>(s => when_LongFunction_does_something_interesting(s));
    await owner.LongFunction(progress);
    when_task_completes();
}

void when_LongFunction_does_something_interesting(string message)
{
    this.MyTextBox.Text = message;
}
```

Note that I used `Progress<string>` as an example. Instead of `string`, you can use whatever type works best for your situation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort you put in for helping me.  I am trying this out now and if it works will checkmark it.

Comment: Update: I ended up abandoning the async/await style.  In its place the dialog is launching code on a separately managed thread (so the dialog function can just return) and that code will Invoke the dialog to do updates.  So unfortunately a full test is not possible, but at least the part about the Load event is still useful to me.  Thanks again!